# How do I make clicking a link_to open up a partial only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have these files:

_comment.haml

```
%div.comment{ :id => "comment-#{comment.id}" }
    %hr
    - if current_user && current_user.id == comment.user_id || current_user && current_user.id == reel_user
        = link_to "×", comment_path(comment), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this comment?", :disable_with => "×", :class => 'close', :id => "delete_comment"
    %h4
        = comment.user.first_name
        %small= comment.updated_at
    %p= comment.body
    %p= link_to "Reply", reply_comment_path(comment), :method => :get, :remote => true
```

comments_controller.rb

```
def reply
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @obj = Event.find(@comment.commentable_id)
    @div_id = "comment-#{@comment.id}"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

reply.js.erb

```
$("<%= j render(:partial => 'reply', :locals => { :comment => Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, ""), :parent_comment => @comment }) %>").insertAfter($('#<%= @div_id %>')).show('fast');
```

_reply.haml

```
.reply-form
= form_for comment, :remote => true do |f|
    = f.text_area :body, :input_html => { :rows => "2" }, :label => false
    = f.text_field :commentable_id, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_id
    = f.text_field :commentable_type, :as => :hidden, :value => comment.commentable_type
    = f.text_field :p_comment, :as => :hidden, :value => parent_comment.id
    = f.submit "Reply!", :class => "btn btn-primary", :disable_with => "Submitting…"
```

That's basically the flow of what happens if you click "Reply" in _comment.haml. If you click "Reply", then the partial from _reply.haml opens up underneath the _comment.haml partial. However, if you click "Reply" more than once it will continue opening more _reply partials. How can I make it so that it only opens the form once and if you click it again then nothing happens?

Also, how can I make it so that if there's comment 1 and 2 and the reply partial is open for comment 1, if you click "Reply" on comment 2, it will open up the reply partial for comment 2 and close the partial for comment 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do this.

In `reply.js.erb` before rendering the form, first remove any existing forms on the page, this action should prevent multiple reply forms coming up, and close reply forms from another reply click.

this line goes at the top of `reply.js.erb`

```
$('.reply-form').remove();
```

One side-effect of this answer is that if a person starts filling in the reply form and then they click on "Reply" again before they submit the form, then what they've typed will be lost

Comment: How would I go about removing the existing forms? Also, what would I do if I want the Reply to stay there?

Comment: Actually I've just realised this is simpler than I thought. I'll improve my answer

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to remove all the existing forms. But do you know a way of preventing "Reply" from loading multiple uploads without hiding the "Reply" button.

Comment: What do you mean by "loading multiple uploads without hitting the reply button"?

Comment: hiding not hitting. So you're original answer for preventing a partial to show up every time you click "Reply" was to hide "Reply" after you click it. But how can I solve the problem without having to hide "Reply"

Comment: Forget my original answer, it's not needed, that's why I replaced it. This answer covers everything in a simple way. It doesn't prevent the "Reply" button from opening another form, but it closes the first form, so there'll only ever be one open.

Comment: Ahh got it. Works great!